# PHP 7.3 Startup error pdo_pgsql.so: undefined symbol: pdo_throw_exception

Tags: php, ubuntu, pdo, bitnami, php-extension

I have a bitnami lampstack with php 7.3 and I am unable to enable **pdo_pgsql**.
(it should be there by default, but it isn't.)

Here is what I did:

- add php repository `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php && sudo apt-get update`
- install pdo_pgsql `sudo apt install phpX.X-pdo-pgsql`
- copy the pdo_pgsql.so file (from: `/usr/lib/php/{timestamp}/`) to `/opt/bitnami/php/lib/php/extensions/pdo_pgsql.so`
- install these packages: `sudo apt install phpX.X-dev libpq-dev postgresql`
- enable extension in php.ini (/opt/bitnami/php/etc/php.ini) `extension=pdo_pgsql.so`

I tried this on php 8.0 and it worked, but on php 7.3 it outputs this errror when I do `php -m`:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_pgsql.so' (tried: 
/opt/bitnami/php/lib/php/extensions/pdo_pgsql.so 
(/opt/bitnami/php/lib/php/extensions/pdo_pgsql.so: undefined symbol: pdo_throw_exception), 
/opt/bitnami/php/lib/php/extensions/pdo_pgsql.so.so 
(/opt/bitnami/php/lib/php/extensions/pdo_pgsql.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No 
such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
```

And according to `php -m` and `phpinfo()` pdo_pgsql is not loaded. (The `PDO` extension is enabled)
The server is running ubuntu 20.04.

Anyone has any suggestions on how to enable it?

Comment: Why would anyone even consider some "bitnami" stuff instead of just installing software the usual way with apt?

Comment: Sadly that is not an option for me, my workplace does it this way.